# How to create a calculated column that gives date excluding weekends?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a SharePoint list with "Request raised date" and "No. of days" by which the request should be completed.

Now, I want another Date column which adds 'No. of days' to the "Request raised" date resulting in a estimated date of request completion that excludes weekends Saturdays and Sundays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula like below for your calculated date column (estimated date of request completion):

```
=[Request raised date] + [No. of days] + IF(WEEKDAY([Request raised date],3) < 5, 1 + FLOOR(([No. of days] - 6 + WEEKDAY([Request raised date], 3)) / 5, 1) * 2, 7 - WEEKDAY([Request raised date], 2) + FLOOR(([No. of days] - 1) / 5, 1) * 2)
```

**Reference**: [Exclude weekends](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268607/exclude-weekends)

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.